# Problems with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, tags

Hi I've been struggeling with this too many hours now. I can't see whats wrong with it.

Here's a link to the source code: [jsfiddle.net/jPPjr/7](http://jsfiddle.net/jPPjr/7)

I didn't want the little box so I removed it from the code.

When I type in one field the other should change its value and vice versa. But when I type green nothing happens. It works for me in jsfiddle but not when I put it in a php-file and use my own tags.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">

var inputA = document.getElementById("color");
var inputB = document.getElementById("code");

inputA.onkeyup = function() {
   var v = this.value.toLowerCase();
    if (colormapping.color2code[v]){
       inputB.value = colormapping.color2code[v];
    } else {
        inputB.value = '';
    }
   }
inputB.onkeyup = function() {
   var v = this.value.toUpperCase();
    if (colormapping.code2color[v]){
        inputA.value = colormapping.code2color[v];
    } else {
        inputA.value = '';
    }
}
colormapping = {
    color2code:{
       green : '#008000',
       red   : '#FF0000'
    },
    code2color:{
       '#008000':'green',
       '#FF0000':'red'
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
Name:<br />
<input id="color"><br />
Code:<br />
<input id="code">

</body>
</html>
```

The code should work (accordning to me) but it doesnt...This is how far I've come. The problem probably is my tags. Why is it not working? :/

Sry for stupid post!

Comment: Doesn't work isn't an error message nor a problem description.

Comment: tell us what exactly happened when you run this code

Comment: Tell us exactly what **should** happen when you run this and what **actually** happens. Your JS fiddle seems to work fine to me.

Comment: sorry I added it, also it's not my JS fiddle :P

Comment: You need to post the code that doesn't work, not the code from the fiddle that does. If the problem is in your tags, we need to see them.

Comment: It's because the DOM isn't ready yet when the script is executed so `inputA` and `inputB` refer to nothing. jsfiddle puts the JavaScript to an onLoad event by default, that's why it works there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your

```
<script>
...
</script>
```

from the HTML head *below* the input fields. `document.getElementById(...)` does not work "forward", so your `inputA` and `inputB` are `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Your script will be executed before the page is fully loaded, so yu should make it execute only after the page is fully loaded. Like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  onload = function() { //wrap your code with this

    var inputA = document.getElementById("color");
    var inputB = document.getElementById("code");

    inputA.onkeyup = function() {
       var v = this.value.toLowerCase();
        if (colormapping.color2code[v]){
           inputB.value = colormapping.color2code[v];
        } else {
            inputB.value = '';
        }
       }
    inputB.onkeyup = function() {
       var v = this.value.toUpperCase();
        if (colormapping.code2color[v]){
            inputA.value = colormapping.code2color[v];
        } else {
            inputA.value = '';
        }
    }
    colormapping = {
        color2code:{
           green : '#008000',
           red   : '#FF0000'
        },
        code2color:{
           '#008000':'green',
           '#FF0000':'red'
        }
    }

  }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
Name:<br />
<input id="color"><br />
Code:<br />
<input id="code">

</body>
</html>
```